# Load data from database into highchart in MVC php using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, highcharts

I am using MVC for Entity Framework & developing aa application & I want to upload data from database to show it into highchart's column-drilldown chart ?

My Code For Binding is as below:

```
$result = mysql_query("select s.id, s.stage_name as stage, coalesce(sum(o.potential) *  (s.stage_weight / 100),0) as w_pot FROM s_stages as s 
left join opps as o
WHERE o.buy_stage = s.id");
$model["chart"]=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($model["chart"],
        array(  
            "id"=>$row["s.id"],
            "name"=>$row["stage"],
            "w_pot"=>$row["w_pot"]
         ));
}
```

and in view I have written code as below with its script code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="span6" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 21.63,
                    color: colors[1],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Firefox versions',
                        categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 11.94,
                    color: colors[2],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Chrome versions',
                        categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                            'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                        data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                        color: colors[2]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 7.15,
                    color: colors[3],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Safari versions',
                        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                        color: colors[3]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 2.14,
                    color: colors[4],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Opera versions',
                        categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                        data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                        color: colors[4]
                    }
                }];

        function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
chart.series[0].remove(false);
chart.addSeries({
name: name,
data: data,
color: color || 'white'
}, false);
chart.redraw();
        }

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: 
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                    setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                                } else { // restore
                                    setChart(name, categories, data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: colors[0],
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.y +'%';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var point = this.point,
                        s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                    if (point.drilldown) {
                        s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                    } else {
                        s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: name,
                data: data,
                color: 'white'
            }],
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the table structure of s_stages and opps?

Comment: I just want to display chart for those 3 fields which I had fetched at the time of Binding. and want to display those in chart with (y as w_pot) & (x as stage).

Comment: can anybody give me answer ASAP.........

Comment: post the result here, when you run this query. with data, we cant give the actual result.
"select s.id, s.stage_name as stage, coalesce(sum(o.potential) *  (s.stage_weight / 100),0) as w_pot FROM s_stages as s 
left join opps as o
WHERE o.buy_stage = s.id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Graph</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php

$result = mysql_query("select s.id, s.stage_name as stage, coalesce(sum(o.potential) *  (s.stage_weight / 100),0) as w_pot FROM s_stages as s 
left join opps as o
WHERE o.buy_stage = s.id");
$stagearray=array();
    $wt_arr=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $sname="'".$row["stage"]."'";
    array_push($stagearray,$sname);
    array_push($wt_arr,$row["w_pot"]);
}

$categories=implode(",",$stagearray);
$ponts_str=implode(",",$wt_arr);

?>

<div id="container" class="span6" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stages'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [<?php echo $categories;?>]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Points'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                shadow: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'Stages',
                data: [<?php echo $ponts_str;?>]

            }]
        });
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```